# How to have a certain position and size of window in FireFox on Windows for a specific website?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox

I use FireFox on Windows 10 for different purposes and it would be convenient for some websites to use predefined FireFox screen positions and sizes.

For example:

1. Show superuser.com in small window at left
2. Show cppreference.com in larger window at top right
3. etc.

Is there a chance to accomplish this? For example, I am thinking about making shortcuts on desktop for the sites and then setting initial windows' positions and sizes in them, but I don't see how.

I don't want to use aside software for this, can this be achieved with build-in Windows 10 and FireFox features?

Comment: There are multiple add-ons available that allow for window size and position presets, with keyboard shortcuts. Not sure-specific though. Would that be acceptable for you? Firefox can't do this by itself.

Comment: @DanielB, thank you. I would prefer build-in Windows and FireFox features. I don't like add-ons, most of them are not certified or secure. I think about something like to create a shortcut to FF on desktop and set windows parameters as command line. I guess, there should be such a way.

Comment: There are no [Firefox command line arguments](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions) to set window size/position.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I expect those to be Windows application parameters. For example, any console application has these parameters (see properties of Command Prompt window, Layout tab). I expect there is a way to handle this with other windows applications/shortcuts, but can't see the tab Layout there. Maybe could be achieved with some command line params common for all Windows applications.

Comment: Firefox is not a console application.

Comment: "I expect there is a way to handle this with other windows applications/shortcuts, but can't see the tab Layout there. Maybe could be achieved with some command line params common for all Windows applications."—That's no and no, I'm afraid. If your requirements won't change, what you want is impossible.

Comment: @DanielB, challenge taken. :) Let's start with the following requirements relaxing: is this possible with safe tools from known companies like MS, Google, etc.? For example, if [resizer](https://winaero.com/how-to-resize-a-window-to-a-specific-size-or-move-it-to-specific-position/) or some tools from [here](https://whatsoftware.com/how-to-resize-an-unresizable-window-or-dialog-box/) would be from 100% trusted sources, it would work. At the end of the day Windows stores somewhere windows positions.

Comment: You can have multiple Firefox profiles. Create as needed.